What exactly should be included in the dependency array of useEffect?
What's the recommended approach for determining which states to include in useEffect's dependency array?
I thought I should only pass states that I wanna watch over for changes and fire the useEffect based on those changes.
For example in the following useEffect I only passed actionData on the dependency list as I this useEffect needs to be fired when I get some specific actionData. But I'm getting the following warning:

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formState'. Either
include it or remove the dependency array.

The context of the useEffect: This useEffect is used to populate data for an edit modal. The modal allows users to modify a product's selected variants. Triggered by an 'edit' button click, a POST request is made to a Remix action, and the response is fetched using const actionData = useActionData();. The useEffect should only run when productVariants data is available from the action.
There is no need to fire the useEffect on changes of the formState properties unless I get productVariants data from the action.
useEffect(() => {
  const currentState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formState));

  if (actionData && actionData?.target === "productVariants" && currentState.selectedProducts.length > 0) {

    // Finding the product from the formStates selectedProducts array
    const selectedProduct = currentState.selectedProducts.find(product => product.selectionId === actionData.selectionId );

    const selectedVariantIdsAndQty = selectedProduct?.variants.map(variant => ({
      variantId: variant.variantId,
      variantQty: variant.quantity,
      title: variant.title,
      price: variant.price,
      selectedOptionsValue: variant.selectedOptionsValue,
    }));    // Extract already selected product variants Id and qty

    // Setting the selected variants with id and qty in the selectedVariants array
    setSelectedProductVariantsAndQty(selectedVariantIdsAndQty);

    // Setting all variants of this product in the allProductVariants array
    setAllProductVariants(actionData);

    // Setting modal loading state to false. 
    setModalLoading(false);
  }
}, [actionData]);


Side note: sicne actionData seems to be an object, make sure that actionData is either memoized properly, or that the very same object (not just an equal one) is returned by useActionData(). Or add all primitive properties and subproperties to the dependency array instead. Otherwise it won't behave as expected.

"What exactly should be included in the dependency array of useEffect?" - Anything that is an external (to the effect but within the component body) reference. Or in nearly 100% of the use cases whatever the linter is telling you is missing. In your code formState appears to be one of these external variables.

In short: any data that affects the computation of the effect.
ESLint is warning you because it clearly looks like formState affects what that function does (via currentState.selectedProducts).
If formState isn't a dependency for that effect, that effect won't be re-run when you change the selected products in the form (or at least that's what I'd assume what formState.selectedProducts is).
The whole deep-copy of formState with JSON stringifying/parsing is unnecessary, though. You should just directly use formState.selectedProducts, á la
if (actionData && actionData?.target === "productVariants" && formState.selectedProducts.length > 0) {

and then have [actionData, formState.selectedProducts] as your dependencies to avoid the effect running every time anything in the form state changes. (This of course assumes that formState.selectedProducts doesn't get mutated internally, like are the rules with any and all state atoms in React.)
Chances are, though, that this shouldn't be an effect at all, but an useMemo to simply derive more data from some other state. It's hard to tell without more context, but here's what it could look like as such:
const selectedProducts = formState.selectedProducts;

const { loading, variantsAndQty, allProductVariants } = React.useMemo(() => {
  if (actionData?.target === "productVariants" && selectedProducts.length > 0) {
    // Finding the product from the formStates selectedProducts array
    const selectedProduct = selectedProducts.find((product) => product.selectionId === actionData.selectionId);

    const selectedVariantIdsAndQty = selectedProduct?.variants.map((variant) => ({
      variantId: variant.variantId,
      variantQty: variant.quantity,
      title: variant.title,
      price: variant.price,
      selectedOptionsValue: variant.selectedOptionsValue,
    }));
    return {
      loading: false,
      variantsAndQty: selectedVariantIdsAndQty,
      allProductVariants: actionData,
    };
  } else {
    return {
      loading: true,
      variantsAndQty: [],
      allProductVariants: [],
    };
  }
}, [actionData, selectedProducts]);


Thanks for the explanation. If I add selectedProducts in the dependency array then wouldn't fire every time anything changes on the selectedProducts array?
The formState and selectedProducts are quite complex structure that changes quite frquently based on various changes.

Yes, it would. And isn't that what you want? If the product shown by this... whatever component is no longer selected in selectedProducts, it shouldn't show some phantom variants for it?

No, this effect is used to edit the list of selected product variants. My selected product array have a list of selected variants. Then when the user clicks edit then I make a request to action function that makes a POST request to the server and fetches all the variants list for that selected product that I get using actionData and set as setAllProductVariants(). Then I setSelectedProductVariantsAndQty() based on the already selected variants and their quantity. This is used to show the selected variants as selected and unselected ones as unselected.

Then it sounds like these state changes should happen directly after the request finishes, not as an effect.

I think it's because the formState is an object that contains information about the entire form state. And it helps you keep track of the user's interaction with the form. For example, it could be isDirty or dirtyFields.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
